# Using Java 8 Streams, how to find the max for a given element in a HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a HashMap of Products. Each Product has a Price. I know how to find the Product with the max Price. But using Java 8 Streams is really puzzling me.  I tried this but no luck:

```
public Product getMostExpensiveProduct(HashMap<Integer, Product> items) {

    Product maxPriceProduct = items.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .reduce((Product a, Product b) ->
                    a.getPrice() < b.getPrice() ? b : a);

    return maxPriceProduct;
}
```

Comment: your are passing a `Map` btw, where you would only need a `Collection`; the key form the map is not used in any way, so its sort of useless

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first problem is that since you want to find the max `Product` by price then it's better to use `items.values()` as the source for the stream as then you'll have a `Stream<Product>` instead of a `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, Product>>`.

Second, the `reduce` operation doesn't have the correct types. So, to make your current code work you'll need to do something along the lines of:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Product>> result = 
      items.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .reduce((Map.Entry<Integer, Product> a, Map.Entry<Integer, Product> b) ->
                        a.getValue().getPrice() < b.getValue().getPrice() ? b : a);

return result.isPresent() ? result.get().getValue() : null;
```

Third, this overload of the `reduce` operation returns an `Optional<T>` so the receiver type of the result set must be an `Optional<T>` as shown above.

Above, we're returning `null` in the case where there is no value present in the Optional.

A much better solution would be to make the method return a type `Optional<Product>`. This documents to you or your colleagues and all future users of your method that it might give an empty value as result.

This is a better alternative to returning `null` as it documents as well as ensures that the user of this method unwraps the return value safely.

nullity can be dangerous at times and leveraging Optional's where appropriate can take you a long way.

With all that taking into account your code becomes:

```
// example without returning an `Optional<T>`

public Product getMostExpensiveProduct(HashMap<Integer, Product> items) {
        Optional<Product> maxPriceProduct = 
           items.values()
                .stream()
                .reduce((Product a, Product b) ->
                        a.getPrice() < b.getPrice() ? b : a);

        return maxPriceProduct.orElse(null);
}
```

// example returning an `Optional<T>`

```
public Optional<Product> getMostExpensiveProduct(HashMap<Integer, Product> items) {
            Optional<Product> maxPriceProduct = 
               items.values()
                    .stream()
                    .reduce((Product a, Product b) ->
                            a.getPrice() < b.getPrice() ? b : a);

            return maxPriceProduct;
 }
```

Anyhow, the `max` method is more appropriate for this task instead of the `reduce`, so it can all be improved to:

```
Optional<Product> maxPriceProduct = 
           items.values()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the default be of type `Product` and not type `Integer`?

Comment: @Aominè Brilliant!

Comment: @RobertoTheLaker you're welcome, I've included more explanaton if you're interested ;).

Comment: `Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice)` gives me the last element of the `items`, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Aominè no I am not the author, but I also faced a same issue and tried above piece of code, but din't work also, I tried `items.values().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice)).findFirst().get();`, but this also gave me same response.

Comment: @NisargPatilI I cannot deduce the problem like that, unfortunately, it's better you post a question detailing what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried to accomplish the task and what doesn't work. other people as well as me if I am free will be willing to help.

Comment: @Aominè good answer. just notice that passing a `Map` is not even needed at all, a Collection would suffice.

Comment: @Eugene could not agree more. seriously I could have written a two-three page book about all the things that came in my head at the time of the writing the answer. in regards to Optional's as well as changing the method signature to something like `getMostExpensiveProduct(Collection<Product> items)` and then simply stream over that and collect the result. I objected to do such things as 1) it involves information that doesn't necessarily solve the issue at hand. 2) it's long-winded.

Comment: @Aominè the stream solution for a Collection btw vs `Collections.max` has it's interesting things... theoretically if you pass a `TreeSet` where a collection would be expected, the stream internals could detected that and simply do a `findFirst().get()` for example, such improvements are not made at the moment - neither in `stream` nor `Collections.max`...

Comment: @Aominè and taking this further... `...sorted(..)... maxBy(..)` could theoretically be improved also the same way, but as far as I looked at the code, its not done at the moment

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed that passing a `HashMap<Integer, Product>` makes no sense since you are not using the `Key` in any way, so this could have been written to take a `Collection<Product>` as an argument, so it would become:

```
public Product getMostExpensiveProduct(Collection<Product> products) {
    return Collections.max(products, Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice));
}
```

But then, this would be a method with a single line, so you could just call it in place where you need it instead:

```
Collections.max(items.values(), Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice));
```

The downside is that this would throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the incoming `Collection` is empty.

*Or* if you care about all the checks of null and empty collection (and you should):

```
public Optional<Product> getMostExpensiveProduct(Collection<Product> products) {
    if(products == null || products.isEmpty()){
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(Collections.max(
            products, Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getPrice)));
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. depending on whether or not the OP is happy with a `NoSuchElementException` if the collection is empty. a simple solution would just be to check for `items.isEmpty()` before the call to `Collections.max` and then return `null`( if deemed appropriate that is), but then again this goes to explain why it's ideal to use Optional in this specific case and then the caller of this method can decide what to do in the "no value" case. +1